# Overwrite parent's tag (ng-click)

Tags: html, angularjs, pug

I have an angularJS webapp. I have a table with clickable rows (jade):

```
tr(ng-click='hello()')
   td hello
   td world
```

I would like to overwrite the ng-click in one of my 'td' such as:

```
tr(ng-click='hello()')
   td hello
   td(ng-click='') world
```

I could put the ng-click='hello' in my first td instead of inside the tr but if I do that, only the text will be clickable!

Any solution to overwrite ng-click inside the td?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just bind the whole td `<td ng-click="hello()"></td>`. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wLPVh/1/